# ubuntu uvcvideo integrated camera disconnects

Tags: 14.04, webcam

I have `Acer V3-771g` laptop with `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` installed and I have the following issue with the integrated webcam (it's uvcvideo):

When I'm trying to enable camera via skype/google+/cheese I see it's being enabled & disables quickly so I'm not able to use it.

I've tried to reinstall `uvcvideo module` via:

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo sudo modprobe -v uvcvideo
```

but it doesn't help.

Here's my dmesg result: http://pastebin.com/anjBnnyz

If anyone got any idea how to fix it, please help.

BR